# Update EGit to 2.3 or higher in Spring Tool Suite 3.3.0

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit, spring-tool-suite

I've Spring Tool Suite 3.3.0 installed and it comes with EGit 2.2.0. Now I need EGit 2.3.0 or higher and so I have to uninstall the 2.2.0 to install 2.3.0. I can't install the new version because Eclipse detect a conflict with the older version.

The problem is that I can't follow the standard uninstall procedure (Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details), because, since EGit comes with Spring Tool Suite Package, the Uninstall button is disabled for it.

I also tried to delete feature and plugins (`org.eclipse.egit`, `org.eclipse.egit.mylyn`, `org.eclipse.mylyn.github.feature`) and then reboot eclipse with -clean option, but the conflict is still here.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it happens because Spring Tool Suite 3.3.0 feature or one of its included/required feature probably references EGit feature as a requirement with mach rule 'equal' or 'equivalent'.

You can try install STS piece by piece instead of one root feature and see if it helps. You can see hierarchy for installed features in Help->About dialog.

Comment: +1 for starting with [Standard or Java Eclipse package](http://eclipse.org/downloads/) and installing Spring Tool Suite on top.

Comment: I fear it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with STS (3.6.1.RELEASE) and managed to solve following these steps:

1. close STS
2. remove all the features and plugins having *git* (also jgit)
3. edit the artifacts.xml in your STS installation and delete all the *git* artifacts
4. reboot STS with -clean option
5. open the "Help > Install new software" dialog and add the EGit main update site:

   ```
      http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates
   ```
6. in the "Help > Install new software" dialog select the newly added site in the "work with" selection list
7. select all the available items and install
8. restart eclipse.

At the end EGit was installed and since then it is working.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but STS still thinks that I have egit/jgit/git installed as part of the org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.3.201411281410-RELEASE-e42 pkg.  Which, incidentally, I can't seem to find anywhere.